# Can I get current location every 10 seconds after app is killed or background in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, background, location, background-process

1

In my project, I want to track user location. For that, I want to update user current location based on location accuracy(for High-> 15 min and Low -> 1 hour). When application run or in the background than I can update location but after kill application from the background, can't update location. I used the timer to call it but after kill the app(from background), it does not work.

So now what I do to update location based on location accuracy if the user did not run the app in the background also.

Please give any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For background and after a kill [Background Geolocation(@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation). Please refer below code

```js
   BackgroundGeolocation.removeAllListeners();
        BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
            desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.HIGH_ACCURACY,
            stationaryRadius: 50,
            distanceFilter: 50,
            notificationTitle: 'Background tracking',
            notificationText: 'ENABLED',
            startForeground: false,
            notificationsEnabled: false,
            debug: false,
            startOnBoot: false,
            stopOnTerminate: true,
            locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.ACTIVITY_PROVIDER,
            interval: 1000,
            fastestInterval: 10000,
            activitiesInterval: 10000,
            stopOnStillActivity: false,
        }, res => {
            BackgroundGeolocation.start();
            BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', async (location) => {
                BackgroundGeolocation.stop();
            })
        })
```

Comment: error in installation of @mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation
1: Task failed with an exception.
* Where:Script '/Users/apple/src/demo/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/VERSIONS.gradle' line: 27
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation-common'.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: 2: Task failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation-common'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

Comment: Did you try to link this module via react-native link?

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation#automatic-setup

Comment: I don't know where to put this line
node ./node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/scripts/postlink.js

Comment: This stop fetching location after appx 2 hours in background. Any idea?

Comment: OS might suspense the app. Did you check that?

Answer (score -1):

[react-native-location](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-location) This NPM module will help you to achieve your task. You can configure it as below.

```js
RNLocation.configure({
    distanceFilter: 100, // Meters
    desiredAccuracy: {
      ios: "best",
      android: "balancedPowerAccuracy"
    },
    // Android only
    androidProvider: "auto",
    interval: 5000, // Milliseconds
    fastestInterval: 10000, // Milliseconds
    maxWaitTime: 5000, // Milliseconds
    // iOS Only
    activityType: "other",
    allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates: false,
    headingFilter: 1, // Degrees
    headingOrientation: "portrait",
    pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically: false,
    showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: false,
})
```

Comment: this is not working in the background and after a kill.

Comment: Why would you set `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates: false` if you need updates in the background?!